# KeyboardAvoidingView acting inconsistently in iOS between screen loads, adding white space underneath

Tags: ios, react-native

My app's main screen is relatively simple - a header, a main body that's primarily a text input, and a footer. It's set up like this (I'm simplifying the code to just call out the major structural items):

```
SafeAreaProvider
SafeAreaView  // flex: 1
   KeyboardAvoidingView  // behavior="height", flex: 1, children also have flex: 1
      Header  // fixed height, no flexGrow
      Swipeable  // This lets the user swipe the input left or right; set to flexGrow: 1 and children have style flexGrow: 1
         View
            TextInput  // multiline
      Footer  // fixed height, no flexGrow
```

The bug is that this combination of elements isn't working as I'd expect. First, when the screen first loads, it looks like this, with an empty gap between the footer and the keyboard:

[image: Screenshot with mysterious white space]

Moving to a different screen then back results in the keyboard showing, but the footer getting pushed all the way to the bottom of the screen, ie into the part where SafeArea is supposed to prevent it from going and hidden by the keyboard:

[image: Keyboard pushed to bottom behind the keyboard]
[image: Keyboard hidden, footer at the bottom]

Why is that white gap showing on screen load, and why does the footer go into the SafeArea when the keyboard is dismissed?

Addendum: frustratingly, this bug does not repro when running the app locally on Expo Go - the Footer is flush against the top of the keyboard.

Addendum 2: A mystifying thing about this bug is that it doesn't seem to be consistent. For example, the observation from my original post about going to another screen and back resulting in the footer being too far down into the safearea exclusion part does not happen consistently. Now when I'm loading the app (I haven't changed anything), going to another screen and back results in the Footer being above the safearea exclusion zone as I'd expect.

I wonder if this inconsistency suggests it's some kind of race condition between different parts of the frontend?

Comment: it seems the issue is with styling, not the keyboardAvoidingView, are you using absolute positioning for footer?

Comment: The footer does have absolute positioning and bottom: 0. But that alone doesn't feel like it can be the problem, because often when the keyboard is dismissed, the footer will be at the bottom but above the safearea exclusion zone.

Answer (score 0):

can you add this prop in KeyboardAvoidingView

```
keyboardVerticalOffset={-80}
```

adjust with your requirements

Comment: I don't think this alone can be it, because part of the issue is that this bug happens inconsistently - when going back and forth between different screens, sometimes it's broken as described above, sometimes it works fine