# Component in SafeArea and KeyboardAvoidingView has different positioning on Expo development build vs live App Store Testflight build

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

(This may be the same bug as my [other post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75442579/keyboardavoidingview-acting-inconsistently-in-ios-between-screen-loads-adding-w) but I think I've isolated it to a more specific question)

I have a screen where the components are laid out like this:

```
SafeAreaProvider
SafeAreaView  // flex: 1
   KeyboardAvoidingView  // behavior="height", flex: 1, children also have flex: 1
      Header  // fixed height, no flexGrow
      Swipeable  // This lets the user swipe the input left or right; set to flexGrow: 1 and children have style flexGrow: 1
         View
            TextInput  // multiline
      Footer  // fixed height, no flexGrow
```

In any development build (on my phone or on my computer's iOS simulator), the Footer (blue horizontal section) shows up flush against the top of the keyboard, which is what I want:

[image]

However, when I create a build using `eas build` for the App Store, distribute my app through Testflight, and open that Testflight app on my phone (so same device that runs the development build above just fine), I see this, with the Footer floating a certain number of pixels above the top of the keyboard:

[image]

The amount of mysterious spacing almost feels like the same shift up that SafeArea would create if the Footer were at the bottom of the screen with the keyboard hidden, but I don't know if that's a coincidence. Note that the space under the Footer is a continuation of the white space above the Footer - the Footer is floating on top of it.

What would cause this difference in behavior between the development builds and the production App Store build?

Comment: it will be helpful if you include minimum code to recreate the issue

Answer (score 0):

My best guess as to why this was happening was that it was a race condition between loading up a SafeAreaView, a KeyboardAvoidingView and autofocusing an input.

What I ended up doing was to remove the SafeAreaView, keep the KeyboardAvoidingView, and then begin to set the marginBottom of my Footer component using `useSafeAreaInsets` from `react-native-safe-area-context`  depending on whether the keyboard is showing or not. I also cleaned up the logic around when the input would get focus upon navigation.

Overall, a much clunkier solution, but it seems to work as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to remove `SafeAreaView`

```
import {Platform} from "react-native"

<SafeAreaView  >     
  <KeyboardAvoidingView
    // enum('height', 'position', 'padding')
    behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : undefined}
    keyboardVerticalOffset={100}
  >
```